# How do I align a flow element next to a phrasing element?

Tags: image, html, css

I am relatively new to front-end development so having a bit of an issue in finding the best way to organize a horizontal menu, which will contain a logo and a few menu options. In addition, I want to separate the horizontal menus by a wide |

Not sure how to do that.

This is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
 <header> 
 <img src="/images/logo.png" height="50px" id="front" />
 <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 header {
 background-color: #009000;
 height: 85px;
 position: relative;
 }
 #front {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
 ul li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-right: 34px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Instead of using the pipe character, each list element (gotten with the selector "ul li") has a thin right-hand border. You could also add `<li> | </li>` between each list item.

Also, I'm floating the li elements left, rather than displaying them inline. Not sure if you want the nav inside of the header.

HTML:

```
<header>
  <img src="/images/logo.png" height="70px" id="front" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: #009000;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#front {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
ul li.last {
    border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sam.  yes I need the nav inside the header next to the logo.  Maybe 50px away from the logo..

Comment: Nav is now in the header. To move it away from the logo, just add "margin-left: 50px" (or whatever measure you'd like) to the nav {} section of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  That worked.  Also i noticed that in the header you removed the height I had and used auto.  Is your way better than mine? Just want to know since I can't tell which is better.  Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on the context, but defining a set height (rather than auto) is probably worth it. I changed mine because I wasn't pulling in the image properly and it was bugging me XD.

Comment: Also if I want to make the | bigger, how can i achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: in the ul li {} selector, the border-right property is setting the width of the solid line. Change that and watch the glorious fireworks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20283/discussion-between-kpo-and-sam)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;`.

Also, place `float:left;` inside your `#front` css section to get the navigation inside the header.

Comment: Thanks that helped me align the menu but how do I bring the menu in the header?

Comment: Place float:left inside the #front css bit also.

Comment: OK i tried that but when i implement this change the header from the top has a gap.....

Comment: That's because you have margin-top: 20px in #front. Take that out and it's back to the top.

Comment: Yes.. but maybe becuase yours doesn't have the logo? I used google's.  See mine: http://jsfiddle.net/PUANp/

Comment: Ok, but you kept that margin-top: 20px inside there which I said to take out :P - http://jsfiddle.net/PUANp/1/

Comment: I removed it in my website but it still shows that white gap from the top... In JSfiddle it doesn't show.

Comment: Post all the code then, it must be another element affecting it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would have created this with DIVs instead of ul/li, here is the css that'll get you started:

```
body { margin:0; background-color:#FFFFFF; }
header { background-color:#009000; height:85px; position:relative; }
header:after { content:''; display:block; clear:both; }
header img { float:left; margin:20px 20px 0 20px; }
header ul { list-style-type:none; }
header ul li { float:left; margin-right:34px; border-left:1px solid #000000; padding-left:10px; }
header ul li:first { border:none; padding:0; }
```

A few things you'll see that I did differently are:

1) I used the clear fix system on the header so that when you're using floats, they'll be cleared and you won't have to worry about them after the header.

2) I floated the image left and added some margin to the right.

3) Since you're using ul/li, you need to turn off the bullets with `list-style-type:none;`

4) I floated the li elements and gave them each a border on the left, but then I removed the border and padding on the first li.

You could have also accomplished this by using `display:inline-block;` I feel using DIVs would have been cleaner code, but I didn't want to change your html and instead just showed you how to accomplish this with css.